# How to handle with multiple assets hosts and tinymce-rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, asset-pipeline

I am using tinymce in my app.
https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

I require it in `application.js`

```
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

I moved my assets lately outside to few hostnames.

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets%d.somehost.com"
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = false
```

After that my tinmce broke with error `Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

I guess I have to override at the top of file `tiny_mce_popup.js`:

```
document.domain = 'somehost.com';
```

But how will be the best way to do that since this file is in the gem?

Comment: you could reset the document domain on your main page

Comment: Nope. Then I get error: ``The frame being accessed set 'document.domain' to 'somehost.dev', but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.``

Comment: what happens if you set document.domain = 'somehost.com';  in an own plugin that you load with each of your editors?

Comment: It works but this requires from me to override ``tinymce-rails`` gem and I want to avoid that.

Comment: sry, i have no other approach than that. but why do you need to overwrite tinymce-rails? all you need is an own plugin and to enlarge the tinymce configuration parameter 'plugins'

Comment: Could you give me some hints how to start applying that? Dont know how to start.

Comment: here you will find a tutorial on howto write a tinymce plugin (it is pretty easy):http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin ,to add a plugin to the plugins list look here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:plugins